# Software to swap audio tracks automatically

Tags: audio, audio-recording

Is somewhere out there any software which can swap similar audio tracks ?

For eg. I record video and audio on camera, but I'm also recording the audio with external recorder on the top of the camera. Than, I just want to swap the audio in video with audio from external recorder.

I think it should be fairly easy for the software to detect exact audio track in video and swap it with audio track from external recorder. Definetly easier than doing it manualy.

Thank you!

Comment: PluralEyes https://www.maxon.net/en/red-giant-complete/pluraleyes

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Premiere can help you to line up multiple audio and video recordings. Look at how to make multi-camera sequences and select Audio to synchronise the clips based on their waveforms:

https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/create-multi-camera-source-sequence.html

Comment: DaVinci can also do this, even in the freeware version.